# Linux C read a directory

Tags: c, linux, directory

Hello I want to read from and write to a directory just like reading from and writing to files. I always use the `open`, `read`, `write` and `close` functions, which means I use descriptors. But doing this on a directory doesn't work, the `open` call works, but `read` returns -1 and `errno` is EISDIR. Am I forced to use streams to read a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `read()` and `write()` system calls cannot be used on directories.  Instead, the `getdents()` / `getdents64()` system calls are used to read a directory.  Directories cannot be directly written at all.

Futhermore, glibc does not provide a wrapper for the `getdents()` / `getdents64()` system calls - instead it provides the POSIX-conforming `readdir()` function, which is implemented using those system calls.  Most programs should use `readdir()`, but it is possible to call the system calls directly using `syscall()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @caf pointed out, you should use `readdir` for this purpose. Indeed, one uses a sequence of `opendir`, `readdir`, `closedir` for reading directory files. Futhermore, directories are read only and cannot be written. However, if you are curious about using `getdents` *system call* to read a directory, here is a minimal example without error checking. Here, the function `read_dirent` takes the file descriptor corresponding to your directory and returns a directory entry on each call. The directory name can be passed as a command line argument. The default behavior prints the content of the current working directory. You can read more about `getdents` in [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) or [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man2/getdents.2.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

typedef struct linux_dirent 
{
    long           d_ino;
    off_t          d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    char           d_name[];
} LinuxDirEnt;

LinuxDirEnt *read_dirent(int fd);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    LinuxDirEnt *d;

    fd = open(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".", O_RDONLY);

    printf("inode#  d_reclen  d_name\n");
    while(d = read_dirent(fd))
        printf("%8ld  %4d  %s\n", d->d_ino, d->d_reclen, d->d_name);   

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

LinuxDirEnt *read_dirent(int fd)
{
    static int nread = 0;
    static int bpos = 0;
    static char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    static LinuxDirEnt *d;
    
    if (nread == 0)
    {
        nread = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        if (nread == 0)
            return NULL;
        bpos = 0;
    }
    else
        bpos += d->d_reclen;
    d = (LinuxDirEnt *)(buf + bpos);
    nread -= d->d_reclen; 

    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code here in Stack Overflow ([How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)), that helped me a lot in understanding how it works:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    DIR* dirFile = opendir( "." );
    struct dirent* hFile;
    if ( dirFile ) 
    {
    while (( hFile = readdir( dirFile )) != NULL ) 
    {
       if ( !strcmp( hFile->d_name, "."  )) continue;
       if ( !strcmp( hFile->d_name, ".." )) continue;

     // in linux hidden files all start with '.'
       if ( gIgnoreHidden && ( hFile->d_name[0] == '.' )) continue;

     // dirFile.name is the name of the file. Do whatever string comparison 
     // you want here. Something like:
        if ( strstr( hFile->d_name, ".c" ))
           printf( "found an .txt file: %s", hFile->d_name );
    } 
  closedir( dirFile );
 }
}
```