# Working with Linux directories with file descriptors

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, file-descriptor

Is it possible to work with directories using file descriptors?

I'm trying to open a certain directory and get all of the files/other directories in it.
The files and directories in it are dynamic and so I cant just open each file/directory individually

Note:
I'm purposefully trying to do it without the use of C standard library

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131901/linux-c-read-a-directory

Comment: Im' not sure what you mean by "The files and directories in it are dynamic", well that's usually how things work, files are constantly created/deleted/renamed etc. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: `Is it possible to work` What does it mean to "work"? "Work" in what way? `I'm trying to open a certain directory and get all of the files/other directories in it` how are file descriptors related to this? Are you asking how to work with directories with file descriptors __or__ how to list files and directories in a directory?  `and so I cant just open each file/directory` Why would you "open" them? Do you want to list files and directories in a directory __or__ you want to open each file and directory in a directory?

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own ps without using API functions, and so I need to access the /proc directory directly. (I've started writing it in assembly)

Comment: `opendir` function internally uses `open` and `getdents` system calls. This is also API.

Comment: You want `opendir` and `readdir`.

Comment: When you say "without the use of C standard library", should we understand you to mean "without directly calling any of the functions declared in stdio.h"?  That's a very different thing.

Comment: I confused here many things, I'm new on linux and system programming in general so I'm still trying to figure out what to do.

Comment: Or if your objective is to avoid linking any system libraries at all into your program, then your only alternative is to call system calls directly.  You can do that from C via inline assembly.  In that case, your question is really about the Linux system call suite, not about C.  Not that I see the point to such an effort.

Comment: @John Bollinger
yeah thats what I've been doing, I made assembly procedures in different assembly files and called them from my C code.
I'm lost on how to go on from here.
I've already located the files in /proc I need to read from, but I don't know how to handle the process directories, as they change all the time.

How do I move on from here?
I am doing it because my uncle told me it would teach me a lot about the internals of linux

Comment: Were it me, I would not be writing anything in assembly.  The system's C library already provides efficient, correct, well documented interfaces for actions such as reading directories.  I've reinvented more than a few wheels in my time, but this is more like rediscovering fire.

Comment: @John Bollinger so what do you recommend me do?
When he said "no API functions" what can I use?

Comment: Who is "he"?  And how am I supposed to know what he means by "no API functions"? If you cannot call any functions at all from any of the system libraries then, again, you will have to write assembly functions for executing Linux system calls directly.  If this is an academic assignment with such a requirement, then surely the coursework and materials provide *something* intended to prepare you.